# Is the phrase "Please be informed that" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, formality

I have seen this phrase in many articles. It sounds a little bit odd to me.

Also, what could be an alternative to this? Can I use "please be aware" or "For your information" instead of this phrase?

Comment: What do you think is ungrammatical about the phrase? Do elaborate. Then we can actually address your doubts directly, rather than saying "it's fine", shrugging and moving on, which is not really of help to anybody.

Comment: Yes it's grammatical. E.g. "Please be aware that the event will be cancelled in the event of rain". You could also say "For your information, the event will be cancelled in the event of rain" or "Please be aware the event will be cancelled in the event of rain" but the lack of 'that' makes it less formal.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think OP is confused by the use of the *passive imperative* form (i.e. "be informed"), which is a fairly rare form although perfectly correct. If this question weren't almost 12 years old, I'd suggest you add an answer which addresses this usage :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, "Please be informed that..." is correct, as is "For your information".

Both formulations are common and current.

The former is considered more polite, and is the accepted form in written communication, but it can also be used sarcastically in oral communication by a speaker who wishes to assert authority over a subordinate.

The latter is used in spoken conversation except when particular formality is required. It can also be used assertively but is not an inherently assertive formulation.

'Please be informed that' is more polite than 'This is to inform you that'.  The latter implies authority, so the 'you' becomes an object.

In other words, an object is supposed to be passive, if not powerless.